# Cannot mock Enum values in JUnit 5

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, enums, mockito

I encounter "unnecessary stubbings" error due to the lines where I mock my variable with enum values:

```
when(productProjection.getType()).thenReturn(ProductType.USER_ADDED);
```

I did not mock `ProductType`, but even trying to mock as shown below, it does not make any sense:

```
@Mock
private ProductType productType;
```

So, how should I use enum in my unit test (I use JUnit5)? Or how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, when you see an error like this running a set of tests, but not in the individual test, Mockito is reporting the error against the wrong test.  This is because Mockito doesn't know that you didn't call the stubbed method, until the next test begins.

Imagine you've got tests like this.

```
Test 1:
    Stub method X
    Call method X

Test 2:
    Stub method X

Test 3:
    Stub method X
    Call method X
```

Then test 1 and test 2 will be fine, because you haven't done anything wrong.  But if you're running all the tests in order, then when you start running test 3, Mockito detects that you stubbed a method and didn't call it, in test 2.

Of course, in this case, if you run test 3 by itself, there won't be any kind of warning from Mockito.

My advice would be to look at the test BEFORE the one that's giving you the warning.  Your "unnecessary stubbing" is most likely to be in that one.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kareem, very good explanations. Voted up ;)  However, although I tried to comment out the other test methods completely one by one and left only my test method and private method that I use for creating stubbing instance, it still gives the same error (the lines of my enums) while it does not give when I run only this test method. I also have not `@BeforeEach() setup() {}` method. >>>

Comment: >>> So, the problem may be related to 2 reasons: One of them is Enum, the other one is running test globally or locally. I debugged the enum values and they are used properly in my service method and the result is retrieved according to the enum values. Any idea?

Comment: If you want, I can send you my test method in chat. Thanks in advance and selamun aleykum.

Comment: By the way I marked your reply as answer. However, the problem is not solved completely and I would be happy if you reply my last questions before this comment.

Comment: I've never encountered any problem with stubbing methods that return Enum values.  I've also studied the Mockito code base quite heavily, and I don't know of any reason why stubbing such methods wouldn't work.  But I will say that if my solution didn't solve your problem, you shouldn't mark it as accepted.  That way, somebody else is more likely to come along and try to answer your question.  And if there are details that you think that person might require, such as the code of your test method, it would be much better for you to paste the details into the question itself.

Comment: I think the problem is related to that my test is not completely cover the method and some lines are out of coverage. So, I need to install Jacoco, but cannot use in IntelliJ properly. Do you have any experience? If so, I will point you to my new opened question.